# comparison between the fgets and NULL

Tags: c

I've just seen a strange part of code in the David Griffiths book "Head First C", part 6:

```
island* start = NULL;  island* i = NULL;
island* next = NULL;
char name[80];
for(; fgets(name, 79, stdin) != NULL; i = next) {
    next = create(name);
    if (start == NULL)
        start = next;
    if (i != NULL)
        i->next = next;
}
```

here is the part of source code (if it can be named like that): https://github.com/dogriffiths/HeadFirstC/blob/master/chapter5/Page%20218/code_lots_of_progs.c

line 250.

so, does the comparison between the fgets and NULL really work???

Comment: Yes... http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Comment: On success, `fgets` returns the pointer to the target buffer (`name` in this case).  On EOF or error, it will return `NULL`.

Comment: Would have expected `fgets(name, sizeof name /* or 80 */, stdin)` rather than `fgets(name, 79, stdin)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it works.
fgets returns NULL if there is an Error or there is no next word typed in.